# What happens when an adapters datasource is invalidated during layout?

Tags: android

Say I have an adapter that interfaces with a shared data set. During the layout of a composite view (i.e. listView), getView is called and the adapter is accessed. GetView is called for subsequent elements. The adapter provides direct locked references to elements in the shared data set.

Now the dataset may change from underneath the adapter. In this scenario the adapter would be invalidated when the data set changes. However, it is possible that the data is invalidated while the UI is in a draw or layout phase.

My question is, what happens if another thread invalidates the dataset while the view is iterating through it's children (getView is being called, and the adapter is being accessed)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your backing data looks like and how you've invalidated it, as well as how your getView is implemented. Depending on these things you may get a view that represents old data, new data, or some undefined state which may result in unexpected data or even a NullPointerException or other exception.

A more detailed answer can be provided if you supply more detail in your question about the type of data and adapter. Source code for your adapter, particularly your getView method would also allow a more specific answer.

Comment: We can assume that the backing data is shared, and therefore can change. When it changes, a callback on the adapter is triggered asynchronously. This callback invalidates the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should always modify the contents of your adapter from your UI thread to prevent issues from this. Otherwise you'll occasionally get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, `NullPointerException` or an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I highly recommend the I/O 2010 talk about ListViews if you haven't had a chance to watch it yet, there is a ton of good info in it about how they work and how to optimize them.

[Google I/O 2010 - The World of ListView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: The exceptions are trivial to guard against.